# CSS sprite with pseudo classes in all corners

Tags: html, css

I found [this codepen](http://codepen.io/Puppies4Life/pen/JIAxv) which is using this sprite to add the corners:

[image: ornaments]

with this code:

```
.lol-promo:before,
.lol-promo:after {
  background: url("http://s.cdpn.io/800/ornaments-sprite.png") no-repeat;
  content: "";
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 95px;
}

.lol-promo:after {
  background-position: -95px 0;
  left: auto; right: 0;
}
```

but in the codepen example is using only the top corners, how can i add the bottom corners too, to a simple div? i tried some things like repeating div:after part but is not working. I think its simple but i am not getting the point.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [CSS3 `border-image` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image).

You define how the image will get sliced and the width of the border. [The `slice` rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-slice) takes four values each defining top, right, bottom and left corners of the box respectively. This way, you don't need any pseudo-elements.

Give your markup: `<section class="lol-promo"></section>`..

All you need is this CSS:

```
.lol-promo {
    ...
    border-image: url('//s.cdpn.io/800/ornaments-sprite.png');
    border-image-slice: 40 96 40 96;
    border-image-width: auto;
}
```

The `slice` is based off the image that you referenced to in your question. For any other image, you need to tweak those values depending on how you want the border to appear.

**Example Snippet**:

```css
.lol-promo {
    height: 120px; width: 320px; margin: 16px; padding: 16px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,128,0.1);
    border-image: url('//s.cdpn.io/800/ornaments-sprite.png');
    border-image-slice: 40 96 40 96;
    border-image-width: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="lol-promo">
    <h2>header</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</section>
```

**Example Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/05Lx7eea/

Comment: Wow, thanks... this is clear the best answer, didn't know about this border-image class, perfect solution with less code!

Comment: The only problem i am having with this, is that for some weird reason if i dont have a `border` class before `border-image`, the thing doesn't work, lol.

Answer (score 1):

You can duplicate that div `.lol-promo` and flip the bottom ones vertically with `transform:scale` and `absolute` position them to the bottom right and left of your page. Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/az6juLkq/1/ with the full code.

```
.lol-promo.left,
.lol-promo.right {
   position: absolute;
  -moz-transform: scale(1, -1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, -1);
  -o-transform: scale(1, -1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1, -1);
  transform: scale(1, -1);
}
.lol-promo.left{
   bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
.lol-promo.right {
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
  background-position: -95px 0;
  right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: yea, is a good point, but really is not another alternative to do this without adding two elements in DOM?

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish the flip, you can use a [CSS transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform). This may be done within the [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pseudo-classes) itself if you wish.

```
-moz-transform: scale(1, -1);
-webkit-transform: scale(1, -1);
-o-transform: scale(1, -1);
-ms-transform: scale(1, -1);
transform: scale(1, -1);
```

In the linked example, notice the border is technically `border-top`, yet it appears on the *bottom*.
**CODEPEN**: http://codepen.io/pohuski/pen/bVBpNw

[image]